# SQL Get records past a certain date, higher than a certain value, with a minimum amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a hard time with an SQL query at the moment. I have a list of customer orders, and I want to remove a set of them based on certain criteria:

1. We need to keep at least 6 of each customers' past orders on hand.
2. We need to keep all of the customers orders that occurred within the past 90 days.
3. We need to keep AT LEAST 1 of each customers orders that is older than 90 days (if the customer had 4 orders in the past 90 days, we'll need to keep the 2 from an earlier time to hit the 6 orders requirement.

So, for example, if a customer had 6 orders in the past 90 days, we would keep 7 of their orders (because we include the 1 order from older than 90 days).

If a customer had 21 orders in the past 90 days, we would keep 22 of their orders.

If a customer had 5 orders in the past 90 days, we would keep 6 of their orders.

Here is the query I am using to build a table of their orders:

```
INSERT INTO @OrdersToDelete
SELECT TempOrders.Site, TempOrders.Number, TempOrders.RowNumber, TempOrders.CustomerNumber
FROM (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerNumber ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS 'RowNumber',
        Number,
        OrderDate,
        CustomerNumber
    FROM Orders
) TempOrders
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CustomerNumber ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS 'RowNumber',
        Number,
        CustomerNumber
    FROM SmartOrders
) SmartOrderOrders
    ON TempOrders.Site = SmartOrderOrders.Site
        AND TempOrders.Number = SmartOrderOrders.Number
    WHERE
        (DATEDIFF(dd, OrderDate, GETDATE()) > 90
```

This query returns a list of orders that are up for deletion (older than 90 days). In the WHERE clause, I can also check the order number, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to exclude the customers first order after the 90 days period.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: simplify your requirements, show some sample data and the expected result for the same. even better if you could set up a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Get the rownumbers using a case expression in order by 
--so all the orders within the last 90 days come first
WITH ROWNUMS AS (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNumber 
                   ORDER BY 
                   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, OrderDate, GETDATE()) < 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, 
                   OrderDate DESC) AS 'RowNumber',
Number,
OrderDate,
CustomerNumber
FROM Orders) 
--Get the maximum rownumber per customer in the last 90 days
,MAXROWNUM AS (select CustomerNumber, MAX(rn) maxrn from ROWNUMS 
               where diff<=90 
               group by id)
--Join the previous cte's and get all the orders for a customer in the last 90 days
-- + one more row which is the latest before 90 days
SELECT r.* 
FROM ROWNUMS r
JOIN MAXROWNUM c ON c.CustomerNumber=r.CustomerNumber
WHERE r.rn <= c.maxrn+1 
--use r.rn <= case when c.maxrn <=5 then 5 else c.maxrn end + 1 to get atleast 6 orders per customer
```

Comment: This seems to have worked for me, thanks very much, wish I could have made the question more verbose for you before you answered.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

Start off by creating 3 Common Table Expressions (CTEs).  You can do them as nested subqueries but I find CTEs easier to read and manage, plus they're easier to explain.

```
WITH ninety_day_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.site, temporders.number, temporders.customernumber, temporders.orderdate
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE())),

ninety_day_count_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.customernumber, COUNT(*) AS Order_Count
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    temporders.customernumber),

greater_ninety_day_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.site, temporders.number, temporders.customernumber, temporders.orderdate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY temporders.customernumber ORDER BY temporders.orderdate DESC) AS Row_Number
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate < DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE()))
```

The first CTE, **ninety_day_cte** will grab all the orders within the past 90 days - we need this for all customers and we need all orders.  Simple, we can set this one aside.

The second CTE, **ninety_day_count_cte** is used to determine the total count of orders per customer within the last 90 days.  We need to know this number to determine how many orders older than 90 days we need to grab.

The third CTE, **greater_ninety_day_cte** will grab all orders older than 90 days.  We add the ROW_NUMBER() to rank the orders per customer by order date - this will help us grab the orders we need for the past 90 days.

Now we need to add the query that will grab the orders for the past 90 days:

```
SELECT site, number, customernumber, orderdate
FROM greater_ninety_day_cte AS g
LEFT JOIN ninety_day_count AS c
ON g.customernumber = c.customernumber
WHERE
    g.Row_Number <= CASE
                WHEN  CASE WHEN c.Order_Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.Order_Count END > 6 THEN 1
                ELSE (6 - CASE WHEN c.Order_Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.Order_Count END)
            END
```

This uses the 2nd and 3rd CTEs.  We use a LEFT JOIN so we grab data for customers who only have orders older than 90 days.  The WHERE clause takes the Row_Number from the 3rd CTE and compares it to the Order_Count from the 2nd CTE.  The CASE clauses state that if the Order_Count (Count of orders in the past 90 days) is greater than 6 we only want to pull the Row_Number >= 1, but if the Order_Count is less than 6 then we want to pull the difference (6 - Order_Count).  This should get all the orders older than 90 day that meet the requirements.

Now we only need to get the orders that are less than 90 days.  This is easily done with a UNION ALL statement using the 1st CTE:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT site, number, customernumber, orderdate
FROM ninety_day_cte
```

That should get you all the results you need.  At least 6 orders and at least 1 order older than 90 days.

Here's the full query altogether:

```
WITH ninety_day_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.site, temporders.number, temporders.customernumber, temporders.orderdate
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE())),

ninety_day_count_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.customernumber, COUNT(*) AS Order_Count
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    temporders.customernumber),

greater_ninety_day_cte
AS
(SELECT temporders.site, temporders.number, temporders.customernumber, temporders.orderdate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY temporders.customernumber ORDER BY temporders.orderdate DESC) AS Row_Number
FROM orders
WHERE
    temporders.orderdate < DATEADD(DAY,-ninety,GETDATE()))

SELECT site, number, customernumber, orderdate
FROM greater_ninety_day_cte AS g
LEFT JOIN ninety_day_count AS c
ON g.customernumber = c.customernumber
WHERE
    g.Row_Number <= CASE
                WHEN  CASE WHEN c.Order_Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.Order_Count END > 6 THEN 1
                ELSE (6 - CASE WHEN c.Order_Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.Order_Count END)
            END
UNION ALL
SELECT site, number, customernumber, orderdate
FROM ninety_day_cte
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering, I'll read through all answers here to get a better understanding of how it all works.